# Setting Apache LogFormat value to environment variable

Tags: apache, logging, https, request

I currently have the following LogFormat entry:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t"
```

This entry prints the hostname of the requester as it's first value. I'd like to do filtering based on this value in the following way:

```
SetEnvIf {VALUE_IN_%h} ^10. trusted_network=1
```

I tried with Remote_addr and X-Forwarded-For but they're both empty when set in LogFormat line so I assume they're not populated at all in the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
SetEnvIf REMOTE_ADDR "(.+)" X-Forwarded-For=$1
```

This can now be represented in both LogFormat and as environment variable with %{X-Forwarded-For}e.